# Is this equation only solvable by trial and error?

Tags: finance, maple

This equation comes from an accounting textbook, in a chapter regarding nominal and effective interest rates.

The following equation is presented:  $0.035 = (1+2/M)^M$

The text then indicates the problem was solved by trial and error?

Why it not possible to solve for M in this case? Is there a term for such equations and would the software 'Maple' have a command for solving such equations?

Comment: Your equation has no positive real solution, since the quantity in the parentheses is always greater than 1 for positive $M$.  Are you sure that's supposed to be a $+$?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it over and I'm 'positive' that the sign should be a +.

Comment: Maybe you equation should be $\color{red}{1}.035=(1+2/M)^M$ Please check it.